# How to get contents of current line?

Tags: copy-paste

I want to get contents of the current line(the line with cursor) for my function. What command allows me to achieve this?

Comment: "the line with the cursor" depends on the selected window, since different windows can have different values for `point`. (It should never be a problem, but who knows...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `buffer-substring`:

```
(buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
```

As [Tobias](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15134/how-to-get-contents-of-current-line/15135#comment23450_15135) noted, this also copies properties of text. If you want to avoid that, you might want to go with `buffer-substring-no-properties` instead:

```
(buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
```

Comment: Often it is better to use `buffer-substring-no-properties`.

Comment: @Tobias Included your insight in answer.

Answer (score 14):

Alternative to `buffer-substring`:

```
(thing-at-point 'line)
```

Comment: Be aware that this includes the final newline character if there is one (i.e. always, except maybe for the last line of the buffer) as well as the text properties.